# Submit Credit Card Contribution error with valid payment processor

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, 4.7

After updating to 4.7.30 there is a new "Submit Credit Card Contribution" button under the Contribution tab on a contact, which would be a very welcomed feature but I receive the following error message.

> **Error**
>
> You will need to configure the live settings for your Payment Processor before >you can submit a credit card transactions.

I'm using a valid Sagepay Payment Processor (with test and live credentials) that works elsewhere. I created a dummy test payment processor and that brought up the contribution form just fine. I debugged the code a bit and it seems that it's only returning `BackOffice` processors as the processor mode is not set in AbstractEditPayment.php.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/wmn84ab617rymcz386pkdnj7rc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right - correct behaviour is for that button to only show if there is a valid live processor which returns true for supportsBackOffice

UPDATE - [Patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11743) has now been submitted to avoid loading of this button for invalid processors.

Comment: Am thinking there is some bug that results in the button showing even if no suitable processor exists

Comment: patch on its way

Comment: but the point here is the button should not show for PPs that are not suited. The issue i am hearing others having is it 'used' to work and now doesn't but if that is true then a separate issue

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response! I've applied the patch and that's worked for me.